# Start-BitsTransfer's Destination field is not mandatory

Tags: powershell, microsoft-bits, powershell-5.0

I had a bug in a script where I'd specified `-Description $dest` instead of `-Destination $dest` on a call to `Start-BitsTransfer`.
It didn't error / ran quickly for a small file and took a while for a large one.
As such I think the file was copied to my machine; I just can't find where it was copied to...

**Question**

- Why isn't Destination a mandatory field?
- Where do files go by default / when Destination isn't specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snarky answer to the first part of your question would probably be "because Microsoft said so". Since I wasn't involved in the decision making I can't give you a definitive answer, but example 7 of the cmdlet [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819420.aspx) mentions that

> The destination path cannot use wildcard characters. The destination path supports only a relative directory, a rooted path, *or an implicit directory (the current directory).*

So I would suspect that the parameter was made optional to allow transferring files "here" (to the current working directory) without having to explicitly specify a destination, i.e. for simplicity of use.

Comment: Thanks!  I should have thought to look there; much appreciated.